# Matlab: button callback for "Hold down " event

Tags: matlab

We know how to program Matlab to do something when a button is clicked, which is this:

```
    button= uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','click me',...
   'Position',[260 80 60 20],...
   'Callback','disp ('' The button is clicked'')');
```

So the piece of code or function placed after 'callback' will be called whenever that button is pressed and released.( so the handler will be called only upon release of the button)

However I wanna be able to activate some code whenever the button is held down and not yet released. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must use a callback function for the "ButtonDownFcn" property. From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoije):"

**ButtonDownFcn**

> string or function handle (GUIDE sets this property)
>
> Button-press callback routine. A callback routine that can execute
>   when you press a mouse button while the pointer is on or near a
>   uicontrol. Specifically:
>
> If the uicontrol's Enable property is set to on, the ButtonDownFcn
>   callback executes when you click the right or left mouse button in a
>   5-pixel border around the uicontrol or when you click the right mouse
>   button on the control itself.
>
> If the uicontrol's Enable property is set to inactive or off, the
>   ButtonDownFcn executes when you click the right or left mouse button
>   in the 5-pixel border or on the control itself.
>
> This is useful for implementing actions to interactively modify
>   control object properties, such as size and position, when they are
>   clicked on (using selectmoveresize, for example).
>
> Define this routine as a string that is a valid MATLAB expression or
>   the name of a code file. The expression executes in the MATLAB
>   workspace.
>
> To add a ButtonDownFcn callback in GUIDE, select View Callbacks from
>   the Layout Editor View menu, then select ButtonDownFcn. GUIDE sets
>   this property to the appropriate string and adds the callback to the
>   code file the next time you save the GUI. Alternatively, you can set
>   this property to the string %automatic. The next time you save the
>   GUI, GUIDE sets this property to the appropriate string and adds the
>   callback to the code file.
>
> Use the Callback property to specify the callback routine that
>   executes when you activate the enabled uicontrol (e.g., click a push
>   button).

Comment: It does not work with Enable "on" but works with "Inactive". It will trigger the callback on click but not on holding down.